# Javascript add event listener in a foreach loop only last entry works

Tags: javascript, asp.net, loops, event-listener

I have a function which goes through an Array and adds `<h3>` elements to a div. Then it adds an event listener (an `onclick`) to the current `<h3>` element, but only the last element which goes through the function is set by the `onclick`.

```
var runstr = [];

//txt comes from the content of a tab separated textfile spilt by '\n'
txt.forEach(function (lcb) { //lcb goes through each line of txt
    lcb = lcb.split("   ", 30); //split the line by tab
    //MainContent_Infralist is a div where the <h3> elements are listed and lcb[2] is the title
    document.getElementById("MainContent_Infralist").innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById("MainContent_Infralist").innerHTML + 
        '<h3 class="Infraa" id="' + "Infralist_" + lcb[2] + '">' + lcb[2] + '</h3>';
    //I put the id into an array to get the index of the marker later
    runstr.push("Infralist_" + lcb[2]);

    //I'm working with openlayers here i try to set the entry of 
    //the list.onlick to trigger a mousedown on a marker.
    //And there is the problem: It works, but only for the last entry of my <h3> list...
    document.getElementById("Infralist_" + lcb[2]).onclick = function () {
        var theM = runstr.indexOf("Infralist_" + lcb[2]);
        markers.markers[theM].events.triggerEvent('mousedown');
    };
};
```

Comment: @kamituel You're right, I'm retracting the duplicate vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("MainContent_Infralist").innerHTML = 
     document.getElementById("MainContent_Infralist").innerHTML + 
     '<h3 class="Infraa" id="' + "Infralist_" + lcb[2] + '">' + lcb[2] + '</h3>';
```

Every time you assign to `innerHTML`, you're basically deleting all stuff and adding it all over again. This causes all event listeners to break.

That's the reason why only last one works - it's the only one after assigning which there is no more `innerHTML` manipulation.

To fix this, create your elements using [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and append them using [element.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.appendChild).

It could look like:

```
var header = document.createElement('h3');
header.id = 'Infralist_' + lcb[2];
header.className = 'Infraa';
header.textContent = lcb[2];

document.getElementById('MainContent_Infralist').appendChild(header);

header.onclick = function () {
  // you function here
}
```

Comment: **Thank you very much!!! It works!!!**
I can't vote up yet but when I can I'll do...

Comment: @user2519977 - Glad I helped :) Rule of thumb is not tu use `innerHTML` for DOM manipulation.